# get error java:cannot find symbol class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i am using spring mvc+spring boot hibernate. Suddenly getting this error before i can run application. Below is the error mesage

**C:\Users\User_2\pdrm\src\main\java\com\example\RegisterController.java
Error:(23, 19) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Default_profilesRepository
  location: package com.example
Error:(33, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Default_profilesRepository
  location: class com.example.RegisterController**

here the **RegisterController** class

```
   package com.example;

   import com.example.*;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
   import org.springframework.ui.Model;
   import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
   import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
   import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

   import javax.validation.Valid;
   import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
   import java.math.BigInteger;
   import java.security.MessageDigest;
   import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
   import java.util.Date;

   import java.util.UUID;

   import static jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeString.substr;

    @Controller

    public class RegisterController {

    @Autowired
    private Default_profilesRepository profilesRepository;

@Autowired
private Default_usersRepository usersRepository;

@RequestMapping("/login")
public String Login(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("user", new Default_users());

    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping("/loginProcess")
public String loginProcess(@ModelAttribute(value="user") @Valid Default_users user, BindingResult bindingResultUser)
{
    if(bindingResultUser.hasErrors())
    {
        return "login";
    }

    Default_users user2 = usersRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
    if (user2 != null) {


        String passwordToHash = user.getPassword();
        String saltDB = user2.getSalt();
        String Password = null;
        try {
            // Create MessageDigest instance for MD5
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            //Add password bytes to digest
            md.update(passwordToHash.getBytes());
            //Get the hash's bytes
            byte[] bytes = md.digest();
            //This bytes[] has bytes in decimal format;
            //Convert it to hexadecimal format
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
            //Get complete hashed password in hex format

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        MessageDigest crypt = null;
        try {
            crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        crypt.reset();
        try {
            String tets = passwordToHash + saltDB;
            crypt.update(tets.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Password = new BigInteger(1, crypt.digest()).toString(16);
        System.out.println(user2.getPassword());
        System.out.println(Password);
        System.out.println(saltDB);

        if (Password.equals(user2.getPassword())) {


            return "/home";
        } else {
            return "/login";
        }
    }
    return "/home";
}

@GetMapping("/register")
public String Register(Model model)

{
    model.addAttribute("profile", new Default_profiles());
    model.addAttribute("user", new Default_users());

    return "register";
}

@RequestMapping("/save")
public String Process(@ModelAttribute(value="user") @Valid Default_users user, BindingResult bindingResultUser, WebRequest request, Errors errors, @ModelAttribute(value="profile") @Valid Default_profiles profile, BindingResult bindingResultProfile)

{

    Date date = new Date();
    int unixTime = (int) date.getTime() / 1000;

    Default_users userExists = usersRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
    System.out.println(userExists);
    if (userExists != null) {
        bindingResultUser
                .rejectValue("email", "error.user",
                        "There is already a user registered with the email provided");
    }
    if(bindingResultUser.hasErrors() || bindingResultProfile.hasErrors())
    {
        return "register";
    }

    String passwordToHash = user.getPassword();
    String salt = null;
    String Password = null;
    try {
        // Create MessageDigest instance for MD5
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        //Add password bytes to digest
        md.update(passwordToHash.getBytes());
        //Get the hash's bytes
        byte[] bytes = md.digest();
        //This bytes[] has bytes in decimal format;
        //Convert it to hexadecimal format
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
        //Get complete hashed password in hex format
        salt = sb.toString();
        salt = substr(salt, 0, 6);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    MessageDigest crypt = null;
    try {
        crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    crypt.reset();
    try {
        String tets = passwordToHash + salt;
        crypt.update(tets.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Password = new BigInteger(1, crypt.digest()).toString(16);
    user.setPassword(Password);
    user.setSalt(salt);
    user.setGroup_id(2);
    user.setIp_address("");
    user.setActive(1);
    user.setActivation_code("");
    user.setCreated_on(unixTime);
    user.setLast_login(unixTime);
    user.setForgotten_password_code("");
    user.setRemember_code("hgshd");

    profile.setCreated(date);
    profile.setUpdated(date);
    profile.setCreated_by(unixTime);
    profile.setOrdering_count(0);
    profile.setDisplay_name(user.getEmail());
    profile.setDob(0);
    profile.setGender("");
    profile.setPhone("");
    profile.setAddress_line1("");
    profile.setAddress_line2("");
    profile.setAddress_line3("");
    profile.setPostcode("");
    profile.setUpdated_on(0);
    profile.setCountry("MY");
    profile.setUser_id(user);

    profilesRepository.save(profile);

    return "/result";

      }

     `` }
```

here **Default_profilesRepository**

```
 package com.example;

 import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;


  public interface Default_profilesRepository extends 
   CrudRepository<Default_profiles, Integer> {


   }
```

**config file**

```
package com.example;


 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
  import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
  import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
  import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
  import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
  import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

  import javax.sql.DataSource;

  @Configuration
  @EnableWebSecurity
  @ComponentScan
  public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Qualifier("dataSource")
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "select u from Default_users u where u.email=?");
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.
            authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
}
```

}

**main application**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

  @SpringBootApplication
  @Configuration
  @EnableCaching

  public class PdrmApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PdrmApplication.class, args);
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem by creating package  for each layer.

- **com.example.model**
- **com.example.repository**
- **com.example.controller**
- **com.example.configuration**

Answer (score 1):

There could be various reason for this error. Like missing or wrong component -scan tag...

Can you please share your spring config file too.

Comment: why userRepository dont get error?only profileRepository  has errors

Comment: I think if you comment profilerepository then it will show for userRepository.
Can you please try to add base package to scan in componentscan annotation or you can add package with springbootapplication annotation.

Comment: if i comment profileRepository, i can run the application. i add @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example") in main app. still got same error